# Meaning of Derivative of Summation

Tags: derivatives, reference-request, summation

I wanted to ask something that I wasn't able to find online, and certainly haven't come across in my undergrad studies. Recently, I was solving a problem which had a function of the form
$$
S(n) = \sum _{k=1}^{n}f(n-k).
$$
where $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Notice here that the variable $n$ appears both inside the function $f$ and as a limit in the summation. My question concerns the following:

Certainly, $S$ is a function from the natural numbers to $\mathbb{R}$. In this sense, $S$ is not continuous over $R$ in the usual notion
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow c}S(n) = S(c), 
$$
for $c \in \mathbb{R}$. But still, after plotting out the values of $S(n)$ for natural values, the figure would much resemble a curve. Given this, is it possible to assign a meaningful value to $\partial _n S$? (assuming instead that $S$ be replaced with a function whose values at natural numbers coincide with those of $S$).

I'm pretty sure someone must have come up with this before, but I cannot seem to find any papers on it. I'd gladly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction, mention some notable texts, and give a brief overview of how such a thing is accomplished. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't able to find the word in my head haha

Comment: Okay... so... $S$ is a step function, no?  That is, it is constant everywhere except at a countable number of points (the natural numbers, in fact) where it "jumps".  This function is not differentiable at the jumps, and has derivative zero everywhere else.  Alternatively, you could make sense of the derivative from the point of view of "distributions" or "generalized functions" (see the work of the Soviet mathematician Sobolev, or the somewhat later French mathematician Schwartz).

Comment: I am aware of the work of Schwartz and Sobolev. The core of the matter is that $n$ appears as the upper limit of the summation, and that's where it gets fuzzy for me. If the upper limit was a constant or something else, I'd happily make sense of $S$ as a generalized function.

Comment: I'm not sure why the presence of $n$ as a limit in the summation should cause any problems.  If you have taken calculus, you should have seen Riemann sums that have a similar property.  For example, $$\int_{0}^{1} x^2\,\mathrm{d}x \approx \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2 \frac{1}{n}. $$  Note here that $n$ appears both in the summand and as a limit in the sum.

Comment: The value of the function is not the problem. It's the derivative :) If you can take the derivative of $S$ and give it a meaningful result, please show me!

Comment: Like I said above, it is either zero almost everywhere (since it is constant almost everywhere), or you can interpret it distributionaly.  If you interpret it distributionally, you might try Googling the "formula of jumps".  Basically, you can regard your sum as a linear combination of Heaviside functions.  The derivative of the Heaviside function is a Dirac distribution.  Thus the derivative is a sum of Dirac distributions (plus the usual derivative where it is defined, but in this case, it is zero when it is defined, so we don't have to worry about that).